# focusSearch(int direction)-value of direction?

Tags: android

How to set focus to the first element from the last element in GridView in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use focusSearch() to do this, you need to use setSelectedPosition() instead. Focus search just lets you go to the next/previous focusable view on screen.

Comment: setSelection(position) works only for the focus to change from the first element to the last element. Its not working for the last element to the first element focus change. How is it possible?